# Кластерный и Некластерный Индексы

Tags: sql-server

Объясните, пожалуйста, если у меня есть некластерный индекс на строковом поле и я создам кластерный на поле int будет ли некластерный индекс перестраиваться под кластерный?

Answer (score 2):

Да, индексы будут перестроены:

> If a clustered index is created on a heap with several existing nonclustered indexes, all the nonclustered indexes must be rebuilt so that they contain the clustering key value instead of the row identifier (RID)

Более подробную информацию можно прочитать [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-clustered-indexes?view=sql-server-ver15).